# How to convert a string array to string type in C++, as in concatenate every element together into one string, and use substring on the string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, substring

for example:

Reading file input and stored into

```
char fileInput[200];
```

then I converted it to some sort of string array using

```
string fileStrArr(fileInput);
```

---

the testing output from the file looks like this : 50014002600325041805
how can I use substring with a loop to get every 4-digit char and convert it to a number such as "5001" "4002" "6003"...? so I think I need to make string array into a string first?

Comment: Do you know how to use `for` loops? Do you know that the increment expression in the `for` loop can be any expression, for example `i += 4`? Do you know how to use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)? Then you know all you need to know really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a character array to an object of type std::string is very simply

```
std::string s( fileInput );
```

provided that fileInput is zero terminated. Otherwise you have to use some other std::string constructor

If I have understood you correctly you need something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;

    std::string s( "50014002600325041805" );
    std::vector <int> v;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); )
    {
        std::string t = s.substr( i, N );
        v.push_back( std::stoi( t ) );
        i += t.size();
    }

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5001 4002 6003 2504 1805
```

Comment: thanks i am trying it out, but do you know the simplest way to terminate nulls in a string?

Comment: @KennyLin There is no need to zero-terminate objects of type std::string. You should use methods of the class.

Comment: sorry, I meant the fileInput character array

Comment: @KennyLin The question is unclear. Use a method of reading data that appends the terminating zero itself.